# transparent circle on opaque canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a transparent circle on the HTML Canvas. Here is the code:

```
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    
    canvas.width = 700;
    canvas.height = 700;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    ctx.clearRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
    ctx.moveTo(350, 150);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(350, 150, 80, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
```

I was able to make the rectangle transparent with `globalCompositeOperation` set to `destination-out` but it failed to make the circle fully transparent.
Here is what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) says about `destination-out` operation,

`The existing content is kept where it doesn't overlap the new shape.`

The circle has still some opaque color applied to it. How to make it fully transparent?
Here is the [live](https://codepen.io/Kishan93/pen/xxXpZJK) demo.

Unable to understand what's wrong with the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `beginpath` methods but the directives you use aren't paths.

The fully transparent rectangle is created by the `clearRect` and **not** by the `fillRect` method.

So you should set `fillStyle` to white and then the code works.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 400;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
    ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 150, 150);
    ctx.arc(275, 100, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
    position: relative;
}

img, #canvas {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1635315850978-44cd0b237006?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" alt="" width=600 height=390>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: @JPM I miss understood how the globalCompositeOperation works. Thanks for clearing my doubt.